# Display a checkbox list instead of multiple select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a model `MyModel` with a serialized attribute `a`, describing an array of symbols.

This code works :

```
<% form_for @my_model do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :a, MyModel::AS, :multiple => true) %>
<% end %>
```

The parameters are correct :

```
{ :my_model => { :a => [:a_value1, :a_value2] } }
```

I want to transform this multiple select into a set of checkboxes, like this :

```
<% form_for @my_model do |f| %>
  <% MyModel::AS.each do |a_value|
    <%= f.check_box(:a_value) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It works too, but the parameters are not the same at all :

```
{ :my_model => { :a_value1 => 1, :a_value2 => 1 } }
```

I think of 2 solutions to return to the first solution...

- Transform my `check_box` into `check_box_tag`, replace multiple select, and add some javascript to 'check' select values when user clic on check_box_tags. Then, the parameter will be the same directly in the controller.
- Add a litte code into the controller for 'adapting' my params.

What solution is the less ugly ? Or is there any other one ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I found a solution, using 'multiple' option that I didn't know.

```
<% MyModel::AS.each do |a_value| %>
  <%= f.check_box(:a, { :multiple => true }, a_value) %>
<% end %>
```

Result parameters are a little weird, but it should work.

```
{"my_model" => { "a" => ["0", "a_value1", "0", "a_value2", "0"] }
```

Edit from @Viren : passing `nil` at the end of the function like

```
  <%= f.check_box(:a, { :multiple => true }, a_value, nil) %>
```

works perfectly.

Comment: Pass `nil` at the end end and it would work as expected check [this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box)

Comment: Please edit your answer if you want, there is also an typo there. After `<% MyModel::AS.each do |a_value|` need `%>`. Just saying

Comment: My personal take on this: this would be an excellent way of defining roles that a user may have. That way, role definitions are hard-coded and you don't need any extra joins or queries to grab other data from the database because it's all there in your serialized field. Awesome!

Answer (score 8):

There is another solution worth mentioning that makes it very easy to insert records into the database if you have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` or `has_many` `through` relationship by using the `collection_check_boxes` form helper. [See documentation here.](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes)

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :mymodel_ids, MyModel::AS, :id, :name do |m| %>
  <%= m.check_box %> <%= m.label %>
<% end %>
```

Then, in the controller we would allow the `mymodel_ids` attribute:

```
params.require(:mymodel).permit(:name, mymodel_ids:[])
```

We can also set up a model validation to require that at least one of the checkboxes be checked:

```
validates :mymodel_ids, presence: true
```

An added benefit of this method is that if you later edit the `mymodel` record and uncheck one of the checkboxes, its record will be deleted from the `many_to_many` association table on `save`.

Comment: Is this anywhere in the guides? I couldn't find anything. Could you give me the link? Thanks!

Comment: @Metaphysiker, here's a link to documentation: https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes.

Comment: Should the `presence` validation work correctly with this option? Or since `collection_check_boxes` includes an empty string, does the validation pass even though no checkbox has been checked?

Comment: @TravisSmith The presence validation definitely works, because Rails treats an empty strings as blank input and will not consider it present.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
<% MyModel::AS.each do |a_value| %>
  <%= f.check_box("a[]", a_value) %>  
<% end %>
```

This will make params come to server as follows

```
{ :my_model => { :a => [:a_value1, :a_value2] } }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you already have a select_tag

```
<%= select_tag "filters", options_from_collection_for_select(filter_values, "id", "name", selected_ids), multiple:true, class:"form-control" %>
```

and wants to replace it with check_box_tag, you will need to implement something like this:

```
<div class="checkbox-inline">
    <%= check_box_tag "filters[]", value.id, selected_ids.include?(value.id), { :multiple => true} %>
    <%= value.name %>
</div>
```

notice the ending brackets on the name which is needed to catch check box results in the same parameter.

When I implemented this, the parameters were of the same format between the select_tag and the check_box_tag