# Creating a list or array of objects in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am trying to make it possible for the users of a web application I am building to create lists of objects that they have created.

For example, the user has a list of objects such as *groceries* which could be anything from apples to oranges to pop-tarts.

I would then like it to be possible for me to return all of the groceries added to the database by the user and create a list by selecting those that are supposed to be on their grocery list.

Preferably this would be in a style such that they could click check boxes for the ones they wanted and then click save to create a new list.

I have looked into belongs_to, has_many relationships and tried creating a list object which has many groceries, but I can not figure out the form part of this strategy. I would appreciate any/all advice. Thanks!

Here is the code I have currently, I originally omitted it because I do not think I am on the right path, but here it is anyway just in case/provide more context:

Grocery Model:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :list, optional: true
end
```

List Model

```
class List < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :items
end
```

The List controller

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  layout 'backend'

  def index
    @lists = List.where(user_id: current_user.id)
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @list = List.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @list = List.new(list_params)
    @list.user = current_user

    if @list.save
      redirect_to list_path(@list.id), notice: 'List was successfully created.'
    else
      redirect_to list_path(@list.id), notice: 'List was not created.'
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @list.update(list_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @list, notice: 'List was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @list }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @list.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to lists_url, notice: 'List was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def list_params
      params.require(:list).permit(:name, :items)
    end
end
```

Not sure what to do about form - was trying something along the lines of http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box

Comment: What does your code look like currently?

Comment: Add some code in your question, what exactly you tried

Comment: Sure - added code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would solve this by implementing a third model which keeps the association between the groceries and the list. And then you can handle it in forms by using `:accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

To give an example, here is how I would structure the models:

```
class List < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :list_items,   inverse_of: :list
  has_many :items,        through: :list_items

  # This allows ListItems to be created at the same time as the List, 
  # but will only create it if the :item_id attribute is present
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :list_items, reject_if: proc { |attr| attr[:item_id].blank? }
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :list_items
  has_many :lists,        through: :list_items
end

class ListItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :list, inverse_of: :list_items
  belongs_to :item
end
```

With that model structure in place, here is an example of the view for creating a new List.

```
<h1>New List</h1>
<%= form_for @list do |f| %>
  <% @items.each_with_index do |item, i| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :list_items, ListItem.new, child_index: i do |list_item_form| %>
      <p>
        <%= list_item_form.check_box :item_id, {}, item.id, "" %> <%= item.name %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Create List' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

To explain what is happening here, `@items` is a preloaded variable to has all the Items that can be added to a list. I loop through each Item and I pass it manually to the FormBuilder method `fields_for`.

Because I do this manually, I have to specify the `:child_index` at the same time, otherwise each checkbox would get the same name attribute (i.e. `name="list[list_item_attributes][0][item_id]"`) as the previous item and they would overwrite each others value when being submitted to the server.

And the FormBuilder method `check_box` has the following declaration:

```
def check_box(method, options = {}, checked_value = "1", unchecked_value = "0")
```

So in the above form, I replace those default values so that when a check box is checked, it has the value from `item.id` and if it is not checked, the value is blank. Combine this with the declaration of `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the List model, where we say that it should be rejected if the `:item_id` is blank, and we get the result of only creating ListItems for the checked Items.

The last thing to make this work, is to permit the nested attributes in the controller, like this:

```
def allowed_params
  params.require(:list).permit(list_items_attributes: [:item_id])
end
```

Comment: Please take a look at what I did - this seems rather complicated for my purposes.

Comment: It looks good and as long as it works :) The approach I showcased may be a little complex, yes, and is maybe more suited when you want to add more features like how many of each item you want to add and how many times you have added an Item to different Lists, but if you don't want that, then your approach is fine. As a last note, another way of solving the problem with no :list_id assigned is to create the Item from the association of List, i.e. `@item = @list.items.create(allowed_params)`. That will assign list_id by default

Answer (score 0):

So I found the following question and used it in order to be able to accomplish what I wanted.

[Display a checkbox list instead of multiple select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899550/display-a-checkbox-list-instead-of-multiple-select)

I simply implemented the following

```
<% form_for @list do |f| %>
  <% Item.all.each do |item|
    <%= f.check_box(:items, { :multiple => true }, item.id) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

At which point I had the error that there was no list_id assigned. I made a migration in order to add attirbute "list_id" to Item model, and this fixed it and all works as I wanted.

Any issues?